# Is there a way to count and limit the number of instructions run by gaol?

Tags: rust, sandbox, gaol

I want to use the sandbox application [gaol](https://github.com/servo/gaol) as a way to isolate code running for distributed consensus. Is there a way to count and limit the number of instructions run by the gaol sandbox so that I can kill the sandbox process after a finite instruction limit?

Comment: This question is technically about gaol, but if someone has a solution using Rust in general, it would be appreciated!